# Adding Storage to ESXi host in lab environment

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-server

I currently have a lab environment set up with 2 virtual machines running on a server 2012 hyper-v host. One being an esxi machine and one being a server 2008 machine that has the Vsphere management system on it. I am currently trying to figure out why I cannot seem to add more storage to the esxi host itself.

When I set up the esxi virtual machine initially, I configured it with 1 virtual hard disk. Now that I have the system set up I want to add an additional virtual hard disk to the system. So I went into the hyper-v manager in 2012 and added a new virtual hard disk to the second IDE controller on the esxi machine and booted it back up. The issue is that when I take a look at all available storage on the Vshpere management system, that new disk never shows up no matter how many times I try to refresh the system.

Is there some special process that I need to go through to add a new hard disk that is directly connected to the esxi host?

Comment: You have to add the storage. Refreshing the storage view isn't going to add it. Go to the host Configuration tab in the vSphere client, select Storage, click the Add Storage link and walk through the add storage wizard.

Comment: Get some training

Comment: @joeqwerty even when I go through the wizard, the new virtual disks do not show up in the Select Disk/LUN screen.